# python - replace string with condition yields weird result

Tags: python, string, replace

I wrote a function that replace the letter if the letter is the same as the next letter in the string:

```
word = 'abcdeefghiijkl'

def replace_letter(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i] == word[i+1]:
            word = word.replace(word[i],'7')
    return word

replace_letter(word)
```

This should give me `'abcd7efgh7ijkl'`, but I got `'abcd77fgh77jkl'`. Once the letter is the same with the next one both are replaced with `'7'`.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
word = word.replace(word[i],'7', 1)
```

to indicate that you want to make one character replacement. Calling `replace()` without indicating how many replacements you wish to make will replace any occurrence of the character `"e"` (as found at `word[i]`) by `"7"`.

Comment: I tried this before, but got error "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: @thatMeow; yeah that's true actually. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works, thanks for the quick response. I cannot accept the answer now due to time restriction, will accept in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

the answer above  has a little bug
for example:
when your word = 'ebcdeefghiijkl'
the result of replace_letter(word) will be '7abcdeefgh7ijkl'
you can try this:

```
def replace_letter(word):
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if i!=len(word)-1 and word[i] == word[i+1]:
            result.append('7')
        else:
            result.append(word[i])
    return ''.join(result)
```